# Default gateway fallback via DHCP configuration

Tags: routing, isc-dhcpd

I have a small network, with two routers/Internet connections. I have configured a Raspberry Pi to load balance traffic between these two routers.

I would like to have a redundant setup. If one of the routers/internet connections goes offline, Raspberry Pi is balancing the traffic, but if the Raspberry Pi goes off-line I would like that clients can still get to the Internet by using any of the other two routers.

If I had to manually configure a client to do this I would:

```
ip route add default via raspberrypi
ip route add default via router1 metric 100
ip route add default via router2 metric 200
```

How can I define this via isc dhcpd?

I've been reading the manual, and the value routes for my defined network seems to be a comma separated list. I am unsure if it is possible to setup metric values via dhcp.

Would this be the proper approach?

Regarding how to setup a fallback default gateway. Is DHCP and metric values a good idea or should I use a different mechanism?

Comment: According to [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/tcp/appd_03.htm) you would use `options routers` and specify multiple routers in order of preference.

Comment: Yes, I saw that on the manual. I did a quick test: setting 3 routers at dhcpd.conf, restarted dhcpd and then renewing my client lease, but I just saw one default gateway at my client routing table. I'll try something else tomorrow.

Comment: You might check to see if the client is just ignoring the additional clients. I suppose you could wireshark it to see if the routers are being set correctly in the packet. Supposing you want to dig that deep into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the *option routers* works.

I am not sure why, but it is not working for reserved IPs, that confused me on the tests. Maybe someone can tell me why? 
But it works for all the other computers in the network, the 3 default routes are available with 1, 2 and 3 metric on order alike the list.

Thus:

```
# Network definition dhcpd.conf
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        ## dhcp start  and end IP range ##
        range 192.168.0.20 192.168.0.250;
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;     ## subnet 
        option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255; ## broadcast
        option routers 192.168.0.3, 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2; ## router IP
}
```